# How to link button to another page referring to specific tab?

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel-5, tabs

I had a list of tab on view_profil page:

```
 <div class="panel panel-default">
<ul class="nav nav-pills" id="mytab">
  <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#profil">Profil</a></li>
  <li><a id="keluarga-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#keluarga">Keluarga</a></li>
  <li><a id="kursus-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#kursus">Kursus</a></li>
  <li><a id="akademik-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#akademik">Akademik</a></li>
  <li><a id="anugerah-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#anugerah">Anugerah</a></li>
</ul>
```

I want to link a button from other page to this page but referring to 'keluarga' tab directly.

I used this code for the button:

```
<a href="{{ url('/view_profil/' . $valueItemregistrationkeluarga->ItemRegistrationID.'#keluarga') }}" class="btn btn-warning btn-md">Back</a>
```

I had tried using a few jquery code and javascript but fail..What is the right javascript/jquery for this purpose?

This is jquery used ;

```
<script>
var hash = document.location.hash;
if (hash) {
$('.nav-tabs a[href='+hash+']').tab('show');
} 

// Change hash for page-reload
$('.nav-tabs a').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
window.location.hash = e.target.hash;
});
</script>
```

I had tried numerous script before, this is the latest...

I am using laravel 5 for this application.

But still fail..anyone can help?

Actually where to put this javascript code? in page with the tabs targeted or from the button page?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following link

```
<a href="{{ url('view_profil')}}/{{$valueItemregistrationkeluarga->ItemRegistrationID}}/#keluarga" class="btn btn-warning btn-md">Back</a>
```

wrap your code in a document ready statement

```
<script>
$(function(){
var hash = document.location.hash;
if (hash) {
$('.nav-tabs a[href='+hash+']').tab('show');
} 

// Change hash for page-reload
$('.nav-tabs a').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
window.location.hash = e.target.hash;
});
})
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry madalinivascu, It doesn't work. The output link of your suggestion answer is 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/view_profil3/#keluarga' and page not found.

Comment: I had tried your new answer, it can lead to the reference page but the specified tab #keluarga not activated..

Comment: the address output of link is http://127.0.0.1:8000/view_profil/3/#keluarga

Comment: the main page which is having all the tabs..is not showing url/#tab_name in the url when i navigate through all the tabs..not sure is it caused of bootsrap version etc..now i am using laravel 5.4..

Comment: i had wrapped in .js file and it can link to 127.0.0.1:8000/view_profil/3/#keluarga but it doesn't go to the tab section

Comment: my jquery.min.js file is /*! jQuery v3.1.0 | version..is it related?